# Can you navigate to an anchor in the browser via JavaScript without updating the URL?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a method in the browser in JavaScript that I can use to navigate to an anchor on the page but NOT update the URL fragment?

For example,

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id="GettingStarted">Getting Started</h1>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var anchor = "Getting Started";
window.scrollToHTMLElement(anchor);
```

I don't want to update the URL fragment.

**URL Before:**

http://www.example.com/mypage.html

**URL After:**

http://www.example.com/mypage.html

Comment: you csn do scrollIntoView() on DOMNodes `document.body.scrollIntoView()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
document.getElementById('GettingStarted').scrollIntoView();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('GettingStarted').scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

if you want a smooth animation.

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9prbn7du/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan Heindl points out, `scrollIntoView()` can solve your problem. More specifically, you will have a element you want to go to, and a button (or whatever you want, just not an `a` tag):

```
<h1 id="GettingStarted">Getting Started</h1>
<button type="button" id="trigger">Go</button>
```

Then some simple javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var anchor = document.getElementById('GettingStarted');
    anchor.scrollIntoView();
})
```

Sample result down below:

```js
   document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var anchor = document.getElementById('GettingStarted');
  anchor.scrollIntoView();
})
```

```html
<h1 id="GettingStarted">Getting Started</h1>
<div style="min-height: 150vh"></div>
<button type="button" id="trigger">Go</button>
```